# Sum of object and compute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I've got stat model :

```
Stat(id: integer, points: float, user_id: integer, match_id: integer)
```

right now here's my code:

```
stat = Stat.where.not(points: 0).group(:user_id).sum("points")
```

what I need is to get the sum of points of each player then get how many matches they have then (sum of points / match count). With the code above I can only get the sum of each player.

**EDIT**

```
Stat(id: integer, points: float, user_id: integer, match_id: integer, team_id: integer)
```

For match model:

```
 Match(id: integer, team_a_id: integer, team_b_id: integer)
```

**EDIT**

Here's my code now:

```
stat.each do |f|
  new_value = (f.sum_points.to_f / f.matches_count.to_f)
  f.sum_points = new_value.round(2)
  a << f
end

new_stat = a.sort_by(&:sum_points).reverse.first(10).flatten
```

I have to change the value of `sum_points` on each data what if I got a lot of data so it will take time is there a way to minimize it? What I need is the first top 10.

Comment: What does the `matches` table/model look like? What have you tried? Will this query be ran frequently? (In which case, have you looked into adding a `counter` cache column?)

Comment: Do you need to optimise fetching both values in a single query, or are these two separate queries you need to execute?

Comment: @Tim Sorry I've updated my question. It is for my leaderboard so I think this will be run frequently. Anything would do but if it can be done by single query much better but i don't think it's possible with one query.

Comment: @something can you try this `Stat .select("user_id, ( sum(points) / count(*)) as avg")` ? you will get your output in `avg ` attribute

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume, that every stat has unique `user_id` and `match_id` pair, then the following request will do the trick:

```
Stat
  .group(:user_id)
  .select("user_id, count(*) as matches_count, sum(points) as sum_points")
```

As a result, you'll receive a collection of the following objects:

```
#<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Stat id: nil, user_id: 1>, #<Stat id: nil, user_id: 2>]>
```

Every object has `sum_points` and `matches_count` methods available:

```
stats = Stat
  .group(:user_id)
  .select("user_id, count(*) as matches_count, sum(points) as sum_points")

stats.first.user_id # => returns user_id
stats.first.matches_count # => returns the number of matches played
stats.first.sum_points # => returns the number of points earned
```

Comment: Hmmm it seems like this code gives `matches_count` = to total number of match. I need is number of match that player played.

Comment: And yes you're right user_id and match_id pair is unique.

Comment: the code should give the number of matches the player played, because the query is grouped by `user_id`. Have you tried and received wrong results?

Comment: my bad I got it wrong i've got a default stat with empty match_id so that user can have default 0 stat that's why it's displaying 2 now I've modified it with where.not(match_id: nil). Thank you!